# How to see what key was just pressed in pynput

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener



def on_press(key):
print(f'{key} pressed')


def on_release(key):
print(f'{key} release')
if key == "a":
    play_audio("A0.ogg")
if key == Key.esc:
    return False



with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
listener.join()
```

what I tried was
if key == "a":
play_audio("A0.ogg")

But it doesn't seem to work.
I am also using a listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do that:

```
def on_release(key):
    print(f'{key} release')
    if key.char == 'a': # when press some specific keys, this will raise an Exception.
        play_audio("A0.ogg")
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False
```

Or use this directly:

```
def on_release(key):
    print(f'{key} release')
    if str(key) == 'a':
        play_audio("A0.ogg")
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False
```